# Произношение слов не побуквенно

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Что это за явление, когда в словах с ***о***дит (с ударением на О) не произносят Д? Например, *приходит, уводит.* В "Бриллинтовой руке" как раз такой есть пример. Экскурсовод в начале фильма (11:36) говорит: "Итак, господа, мы с вами нах**ои**мся в так называемом старом городе". Когда так хорошо говорить, а когда нет?

И второй вопрос, близкий к этому, насчёт слов *тысяча, пятьдесят (шестьдесят и др.), сейчас.* Как лучше их произносить: полностью или *тыща, пейсят, щас?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Что касается первого вопроса.** По-простому это явление называется "редукция". Если быть более конкретным, то это - "выпадение интервокальных согласных". Приведу Вам цитату из книги Е. А. Земской "Русская разговорная речь. Лингвистический анализ и проблемы обучения" (2004): "В разговорной речи наблюдается интересное явление, отсутствующее в полном стиле произношения кодифицированного языка, - сильная редукция согласных в положении между гласными. Это явление отчётливо обнаруживается в произношении некоторых широкоупотребительных форм глаголов, например: *видит* может быть произнесено как *виит*, *ходит* - *хоит*. Утрата согласного в положении между гласными в формах глаголов широко распространена в разговорной речи". По-хорошему, гиду бы нужно произносить *находимся,* потому что всё-таки это не разговорная речь (в лингвистике обычно разговорной речью считается "спонтанная, устная литературная речь в условиях непринуждённого неофициального непосредственного персонального общения". В общем, это то, что мы используем, как правило, при общении с родственниками и друзьями). С одной стороны, это, конечно, нарушение литературной нормы, но и криминального в этом тоже ничего нет. Все мы люди :) Нет-нет, но что-нибудь такое, бывает, проскользнёт. Главное, что туристы его понимают)

**Что касается второго вопроса.** *Тыща, пейсят, щас* - это так называемые редуцированные (или "усечённые") разговорные варианты. То есть мы так можем говорить дома при общении с членами семьи или с приятелями, друзьями. Это норма, и никто Вас за такое произнесение не осудит. Попробуйте прислушаться к речи Ваших близких или друзей (ну или к речи других людей на улице, в магазине, общественном транспорте). Убедитесь, что в большинстве своём именно так так эти слова и произносятся (ну и не только эти. Таких редуцированных слов будет много: *здрасьти* вместо *здравствуйте*, *тя* вместо *тебя*, *сёдня* вместо *сегодня* и т. д. В основной своей массе это такие слова, которые мы в повседневной речи употребляем чаще всего). Если Вы общаетесь, например, с человеком незнакомым или малознакомым (то есть с теми людьми, с которыми Вас не связывают более-менее близкие, дружеские или приятельские отношения: с преподавателями в университете, с работодателем, со служащими банка), то лучше, конечно же, произносить полные формы этих слов.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Виктор! "Тя" да, а "сегодня" у меня по крайней мере звучит не совсем "сёдня", а скорее *СЬ + гортанная смычка + одня.* И так же я произношу "театр", причём всегда. И в "здрасьте" у меня что-то среднее между Е и И, но не чистая И точно, поэтому мне естественней писать так, если передаёшь звучание.

Comment: Абсолютно согласен с Вами. При записи того или иного слова Вы ориентируетесь на то, как именно Вы его произносите. Так что варианты имеют место быть. Одно и то же слово два человека могут произнести по-разному. Например, в том же учебнике, из которого я приводил Вам цитату, Е. А. Земская пишет: "Так, фонетисты отмечают более 20 возможностей произношения самого обычного русского приветствия - слова "здравствуйте"."

Comment: В русском "выпадение интервокальных согласных" решительно ни о чем не говорит. Общие слова. Назвать-то можно как угодно, в чем суть этого явления, да и есть ли оно, или это просто безграмотность?

Answer (score 1):

Первое - это или дефект дикции или нарушение орфоэпических норм, вряд ли какое-то отдельное "явление".

Второе - однозначно лучше произносить так, как в орфоэпических словарях. "тыщща" там есть, допустимо при быстрой речи, но "тысяча" все одно лучше. "Пейсят" - там нету, это что очень "пейсато" у вас получилось. А если без пейсов, то "пидисят", "пиисят" даже - нормально. Летчики и прочие моряки-радисты-метеорологи предпочитают "полста", чтоб с "шиисят" не путалось. "Щаз" - это как "тыщща". Можно, если лень произносить отчетливо. Но лучше все-таки "сейчас", особенно если обстановка не слишком располагает к восприятию речевого потока. Аналогичное справедливо применительно к стяженным вариантам многих других слов, включая отчества ("Степаныч" вместо "Степанович", "тятр" вместо "театр" и прочее).

Comment: Ну, "тятр" никто не говорит, просто И или смягчение очень беглые. А "щас" с З на конце — это выпендрёж, нормальные люди С говорят.))) По типу "преведа".

Comment: >> *Аналогичное справедливо применительно к стяженным вариантам многих других слов, включая отчества ("Степаныч" вместо "Степанович"...)* Правильным литературным произношением будет как раз Степаныч, Иваныч, Николаич, Сергеич, Николавна, Сергевна и т.д.

Comment: *Правильным литературным произношением будет как* - нет, это максимум будет разговорным вариантом.

Comment: *Ну, "тятр" никто не говорит, просто И или смягчение очень беглые. * - Вы так безапелляционно это заявляете, словно в Вас Niemand вселился. )))  Говорят, и не только говорят, но даже пишут, причем в ситуации, когда вариант умышленного искажения исключается. Да дело даже не в этом. Вы тоже очень некорректно используете слово "никто".  Про "щаз" - дело не в последнем звуке, он все равно оглушается. Просто это более популярная форма для передачи "щас".

Comment: Про отчества Niemand правильно говорит, я просто на это не отреагировал тогда. С "никто" может и переборщил, может, и правда некоторые говорят.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *Про отчества Niemand правильно говорит, * - Еще не легче. Ну как знаете. Я считал и считаю, что подобное стяжение отчеств, допустимое в разговорной речи, на другом уровне просто неприемлемо. Поэтому говорить, что это "правильное литературное произношение" - невежество, причем воинствующее. "Правильное литературное произношение" - это то, что нормально для любого стиля, а не только, как раньше выражались, на конюшне..

Comment: *С "никто" может и переборщил, может, и правда некоторые говорят.* - не просто некоторые, а очень многие. Причем  - это уже личное наблюдение - как раз люди весьма культурные, которые знают, что такое зияние гласных и что оно чуждо русскому языку. Впрочем, мы далеко ушли от темы.